# Proof verification (elementary) on sets / families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove $\cap_{n \in \mathbf{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}] = \emptyset$

Suppose there exist a $x \in \cap_{n \in \mathbf{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]$. Then let $m = \left\lceil \frac{1}{x} \right\rceil$. Then $x \geq \frac{1}{m}$. But then $x \notin (0,\frac{1}{m+1}]$, so $x \notin \cap_{n \in \mathbf{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]$, leading to a contradiction. Thus $\cap_{n \in \mathbf{N}}(0,\frac{1}{n}]$ is empty.

Comment: The use of contradiction is unnecessary. You can simply take an arbitrary $x>0$, let $m=\lceil 1/x\rceil$ and show that $x$ is not in that set; since $x$ was arbitrary the set must be empty. By the way the fact that $\lceil 1/x\rceil$ exists, i.e., every real number is bounded by some integer, is not completely obvious. If follows from completeness axiom; of course essentially it comes from the construction of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess I cannot construct the real numbers this way then.

Comment: @183orbco3 You don't need completeness for that,  just the Archimedean property.   Lots of incomplete fields are Archimedean (Like the rationals)

Comment: @Alan Well sure...But also complete implies Archimedean.

Comment: @183orbco3 You have to be careful by what you mean for "complete",  the 7 or so different notions are only equivalent in Archimedean fields. For example,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_field  is cauchy-complete but non Archimedean